# How can I rewrite the code for multitheading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, netmiko

I would like to do the multithreading to my code, but have no idea how to start .... Basically the python script will perfrom a "for" loop to a lot of devices (defined in another file "pyntc_devices_list"), to backup config for all devices.

With multithreading, I should run the backup to all devices at the same time, rather than one by one. Much appreciate for the help.

**My code is as below:**

```
from pyntc import ntc_device as NTC
from pyntc_devices_list import Get_Devices_List

all_devices = Get_Devices_List()

for device in all_devices:
    print('Backing up ' + device['name'])
    try:
        DEVICE = NTC(host=device['ip'], username=device['username'], password=device['password'], device_type='cisco_ios$
        DEVICE.open()
    except Exception as unknown_error:
        print('Error: ' + str(unknown_error))
        continue

    back_config = DEVICE.backup_running_config(device['name'] + '.cfg')
    DEVICE.close()
```

**Part of the "pyntc_devices_list"**

```
ESW1 = {
    'name': 'ESW1',
    'ip': '192.168.122.72',
    'username': 'yyc',
    'password': 'cisco',
 }

 ESW2 = {
    'name': 'ESW2',
    'ip': '192.168.122.73',
    'username': 'yyc',
    'password': 'cisco',
 }

 ESW3 = {
    'name': 'ESW3',
    'ip': '192.168.122.74',
    'username': 'yyc',
    'password': 'cisco',
 }

 def Get_Devices_List():
    all_devices = [ESW1, ESW2, ESW3]
    return all_devices
```

Comment: first you have to put code in function and then you can use this function with `threading` (ie `threading.Thread(target=funciton_name)`), `multiprocessing` or other module

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and yes I need to put my code into a function. But in this case, say if I have 200+ devices, do I still need to use multithreading or just multiprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book https://scaling-python.com, with which I am not associated, offers some great solutions for multithreading in python 3.x (and multiprocessing in fact). Here are some of the multithreading options (but I mainly refer the interested reader to the book, from which the code extracts are taken):

1. threading module (examples 2.1, 2.2, 2.3):

```py
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=my_func,args=(...,))
t.start()
t.join()
```

2. concurrent.futures (examples 2.7, 2.8):

```py
from concurrent import futures
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(my_func) for _ in range(...)]
results = [f.result() for f in futures]
```

There are plenty of other routes in the book. I did run into some issues when using futures alongside gunicorn/uwsgi Flask workers - and it's not clear these are resolvable as of now.

Hope that helps (can also update this answer if anyone has any other solutions).

Answer (score 4):

Python has Pool class with a simple map function that gets the todo function and the iterable, try the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pyntc import ntc_device as NTC
from pyntc_devices_list import Get_Devices_List

NUM_OF_PROCESSORS = 5

all_devices = Get_Devices_List()

def backup(device):
    print('Backing up ' + device['name'])
    DEVICE = NTC(host=device['ip'], username=device['username'], password=device['password'], device_type='cisco_ios$
    DEVICE.open()
    back_config = DEVICE.backup_running_config(device['name'] + '.cfg')
    DEVICE.close()


with Pool(NUM_OF_PROCESSORS) as p:
    p.map(backup, all_devices)
```

EDITED: if you want Threadpool use:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

Comment: It's not wrong (although your code has some typos), but the OP was asking for a threaded solution, while yours is a solution with multiple processes (not the same thing)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did learned some differences between multithreading and multiprocessing, if I have 200+ devices (in real world) in the list, Do I still need to use multiprocessing?

Comment: In general if the function uses I/O resources, thread pool is enough.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have just tested the code, it works! And I am trying to add the error handling into my code as well, the idea is, if have issue to connect to a specific device, then use "Exception" to catch the error and use "continue" to backup the next device. But seems "continue" is not compatible with multiprocessing in this case, I get the error "SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop", how can I fix this ?